# Callable : Can we call class methods from different managed package without using namespace?

Tags: apex, managed-package, security-review, callable

**CALLABLE**

> Enables developers to use a common interface to build loosely coupled integrations between Apex classes or triggers, even for code in separate packages.

I have created an LWC component and the controller for that is also inside Managed package (Package A).

And there is another managed package which we are building. (Package B)

Package A, has controller and I am using callable to call the class from Package B like this:

```
        private static final String STRING_TESTPAGECONTROLLERPE = 'TestPageControllerPE';
        Callable extension = (Callable) Type.forName(STRING_TESTPAGECONTROLLERPE).newInstance();
        List<TestWrapper> testWrappers =
                (List<TestWrapper>) extension.call('fetchTestArticles', new Map<String, Object> {});
        return testWrappers;
```

The class `TestPageControllerPE` exists in Package B, and `implements Callable` and is defined as public.

**Question** : Can package A call class from package B  without name space if the called class has callable interface and is public?

**Question** : If not, can I keep the class name in custom label (namespace.TestPageControllerPE), so that I can change the class name from custom label if the Package B name changes? Will there be any security constraints?

Comment: Package B's class must be Global in order to be called. You will also be unable to create an instance of a public class in a managed package that is present in the org and implements the Callable interface.